# How to make a party banner using CSS? (Shown in the pic below)

Tags: html, css

**the half circles banner I want to make**
[image]

I wish to make it on the head of my sites' homepage, like a decoration, but not necessarily in a fixed position.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: I have tried drawing a chain of semi-circles to achieve so, but I wish to find an better alternatives;)

Comment: Here's a start http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/xVzVGZ

Answer (score 2):

Simply `border-radius: 50%;`

```css
.decoration {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -45px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
}
.decoration span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
.decoration span:nth-child(2n+2) {
  background-color: blue;
}
.decoration span:nth-child(3n+3) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="decoration">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

---

Other solution would be to use repeating image with desired pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Use Below code :

```css
span{ 
    float:left;
    height:45px;
    width:90px;
    border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
   -moz-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
   -webkit-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
    background:blue;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div >
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  
</div>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You have to get a image with that semi circles. And then add to your body something like this:

```
body {
  background-image: url("paper.gif");
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```